# Bootstrap Media Queries in Sass - Why Sass cannot read @screen-md-min?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, media-queries

I have the following code snippet in my `SCSS` to modify the `CSS` according to device size.

```
.cu-list-project li{
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: 60%;
    @include project-list;
  }
}
```

But Sass gives the following error:

> *error styles/sass/styles.scss (Line 108: Invalid CSS after "...ia (min-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was
>   "@screen-md-min) {").

Apparently, "`@screen-md-min`" is not recognized by `Sass`. What should I do?
P.S: I know I can change @screen-md-min to 992px but this will not be a best practice. So, I'm looking for a real solution not a workaround. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the bootstrap-sass, you should use `$screen-md-min` e.g.

```
@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) and (max-width: $screen-md-max) {
  @include responsive-visibility('.visible-md');
}
```

From [line 89](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_responsive-utilities.scss) on Github